# Can I use WP_Query to return pages by category?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I'm creating a WordPress site for a theater. I have several performer pages featuring performers with images, bios, etc. I would like to feature one performer on the homepage as a "Featured Performer." I created a category in pages called "Featured-HP." I am trying to return just this one performer to use on the homepage. It is not working at all. Can this even be done?

Here is my code:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'         =>  'page',
'category'          =>  231,
'posts_per_page'    =>  -1
);

// The Query
$featured_performer = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Then to display it...

```
while ( $featured_performer->have_posts() ) :
  $featured_performer->the_post();
  // CODE HERE TO SHOW IMAGE AND NAME
endwhile;
```

Nothing gets returned, though, so, I haven't even gotten to the image and name. Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One of the category parameters in `WP_Query` is `cat` for single category id. So instead of `category` replace it with `cat`.

As follows:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         =>  'page',
    'cat'               =>  231,
    'posts_per_page'    =>  -1
);
```

You can also dig in a little bit deeper into the [**Category Parameters**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)

Comment: Thanks, I tried 'cat' but it doesn't work. I also tried 'category_name' with the category slug, that didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: What's the name of the post type you're referring? Are you using the post type `page` on storing the performers data and adding a custom metaboxes?

Comment: I'm creating just standard pages - like "About Us" for example, a static page. So, I assume that's post type page. I'm not adding custom metaboxes, no. Do I need to?